# CSS i want the above line not to appear i adjust height but it doesn't work

Tags: css

[image]

```
      _after: {
    width: 'full',
    top: '49%',
    left: '50%',
    // height: '99%',
    height: { base: '90%', sm: '133%' },
    content: '"-"',
    position: 'absolute',
    color: 'transparent',
    backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
    backgroundPosition: 'center',
    transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)',
    webkitTransform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)'
  },
```

code is here. Can you tell me what should be set in the css? It happens when I give height but it also expands. I don't want it to expand

Comment: Could you share you HTML code as well

Comment: It needs to be parsed with css.